# Signals receiver in one file (C)

Tags: c, signals

I have a task - checking if I can write a program which receives all the signals. I know I can't, but when I want to write a program, it doesn't work properly. Can it be done in a one .c file by using fork()? There is nothing written to stdout at the moment despite of `"Unknown signal 32"`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void signalReceiver(int number) { 
  printf("There it is - %d\n", number);
}

int main(void) {
  int mypid = getpid();

  for(int i = 1; i <= 64; ++i) { 
      signal(i, signalReceiver);
  }   


  int pid = fork();

  if(pid == 0) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= 64; ++i) { 
        //SKIP the signals which interrupt the state of the program
          if( i != 9 && i != 19) {
            kill(mypid, i);
          }
        }
  } else {
    wait(NULL);
  }

getchar();
return 0; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the OS won't let you register handlers for `SIGKILL` (9) and `SIGSTOP` (19), your libc won't let you register handlers for the reserved signals `32` and `33` (these are used to implement multithreading).

A simple error check would have detected this:

```
  if(SIG_ERR==signal(i, signalReceiver))
  { fprintf(stderr, "no sighandler for %d: %m\n", i); }
```

Later in the output:

```
no sighandler for 9: Invalid argument
no sighandler for 19: Invalid argument
no sighandler for 32: Invalid argument
no sighandler for 33: Invalid argument
```

Now you are getting the signals under 32, however 32 manages to kill your parent process before the handlers manage to get the output out (BTW, `printf` is not safe to use in a signal handler--you should sprintf it to a buffer and `write` it directly). The `Unknown signal 32` message you're getting is from your shell, which detected that its child was terminated with signal 32.

You should be able to get the messages for signals under 32 if you space the kills (e.g., with `usleep(1000)` so the handlers get a chance to finish) or if you run the kills in the same process (in which case each handler will finish before the `kill` function returns).

If you want the process to survive, don't send it signals it hasn't successfully registered handlers for.

Also, `wait` and `getchar` aren't guaranteed to make it through the signal receipts uninterrupted. You should be ready to restart the `wait`, e.g., with:

```
again: if(0>wait(NULL))
if(EINTR==errno) goto again; else perror("wait");
```

Complete modified source:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signalReceiver(int number) { 
    char buf[256] = {0};
    sprintf(buf, "There it is - %d\n", number);
    write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
}

int main(void) {
  int mypid = getpid();

  for(int i = 1; i <= 64; ++i) { 
      if(SIG_ERR==signal(i, signalReceiver))
      { fprintf(stderr, "no sighandler for %d: %m\n", i); }
  }   

  int pid = fork();
  if(0>pid){ perror("fork"); exit(1); }

  if(pid == 0) {

      for(int i = 1; i <= 64; ++i) { 
          //SKIP the signals which interrupt the state of the program
          if( i != 9 && i != 19 && i!=32 && i!=33) {
              kill(mypid, i);
          }
      }
      _exit(0);
  } else {
      again: if(0>wait(NULL))
      if(EINTR==errno) goto again; else perror("wait");
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Pedantically, `sprintf()` isn't async-signal-safe either.  But if you know that the implementation of `sprintf()` you're using doesn't use `malloc()` and `free()` internally, it's usually safe to use.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for the useful comment.